# Pinterest API Error 405 POST Request

Tags: c#, oauth, uwp, pinterest, http-status-code-405

I'm having an issue with sending a POST request for Pinterest in a UWP app I'm working on. I already have the access code from a previous WebAuthenticationBroker function. I've tried using the WebAuthenticationBroker with the UseHttpPost option under options with authenticating async, but, as I've provided my if functions, it returns ERROR. I just get a "message": "405: Method Not Allowed" and "type" : "http". I've looked all over, I've even tried using an HttpClient and PostAsync(), but I couldn't get it to get the access token. Any advise to what I'm doing wrong?

```
private void OutputToken(string TokenUri)
    {
        int tokenString = TokenUri.IndexOf('=');
        string TheTokenUri = TokenUri.Substring(tokenString + 54);
        PinterestReturnedTokenText.Text = TheTokenUri;
        outputToken = TheTokenUri;
    }

    private async void auth()
    {
        try
        {
            string CallbackUrl = "https://localhost/";
            string PinterestUrl = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=" + PinterestClientID + "&client_secret=" + PinterestClientSecret + "&code=" + outputCode;

            Uri StartUri = new Uri(PinterestUrl);
            Uri EndUri = new Uri(CallbackUrl);

            WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.UseHttpPost, StartUri, EndUri);
            if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                OutputToken(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString());
                await GetPinterestNameAsync(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString());
            }
            else if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
            {
                OutputToken("HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                OutputToken("Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Error)
        {
            PinterestReturnedTokenText.Text = "ERROR";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `WebAuthenticationBroker`?

Comment: @FlorianMoser I meant to say the WebAuthenticationBroker class.